# How to create a form for a new item in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to change something i did in 2.8 to 3.

What it does is build a blank object in the model from the show action in the controller like so.

```
@project.tasks.build
```

and then in the show view i can do something like this

```
<% form_for @project do |c| %>
  <% c.fields_for :tasks,  @project.tasks.last do |p| %>
      <%= p.text_field :name, :label => 'add task' %>
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag '+' %>
<% end %>
```

in this instance it would show just the blank record for entry.

in another instance i could remove `.last` and have all the related tasks editable from the show action of the project.

how do I do this in Rails 3? because it's giving me this error.

```
undefined method `name' for #<Array:0xb2b33d8>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad, i forgot `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my model

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, the form_for in rails 3 needs "="

```
<%= form_for @project do |c| %>
```

The info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html might also provide some assistance.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: that just means it wouldn't display it, the code it's complaining is `<%= p.text_field :name, :label => 'add task' %>` with the `:name` hash